# How to compute mutually recursive expressions in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have two expressions:

1. `a = 3 * b + c` ,    with  `c = 1`
2. `b = (a - d) / 5` , with  `d = 1`

I must calculate `a` in `1` starting with `b = 1`, then (with `a` just calculated) I must calculate `b` in `2`.
if the subtraction of `b` in `1` and `b` in `2` is `> 0,25` 
the loop continues calculating `a` in `1` again with the `b` value in `2` and so on,
otherwise it stops.

It needs two iterations and I think I must use the `while` loop but I can't write it down.
Especially I don't know how giving the instruction to take the `b` value calculated in `2` as the first step
of the following iteration.

Comment: The Q is very convoluted. Could you clarify the objective?

Comment: I'm sorry. The first loop is b=1 so a=4 in 1), with a=4 I calculate again b in 2) and i see b=3/5. I subtract this value to the "b" value calculated before so (1-3/5). If this is < 0,25 it's ok. If not i must do the iteration again starting with the last "b" value calculated so b=3/5.

Comment: If none of the answers is what you mean, try to write some code or pseudocode based on them...

Comment: ok... I write the solution I must reach with python. Thanks!!!

Comment: for b=1 ; a=3*b + c= 4
since a=4 ; b=(4-d)/5 = 3/5
 1- (3/5)= 0,4 >0,25

for b=3/5 ; a=3*b + c= 14/5
since a=14/5 ; b=(14/5 - d)/5 =9/25
 3/5 - 9/25 = 6/25 <0,25
end

Comment: @Fra Edit the question and put your code there. And mark it as source code and format it. Please.

Comment: @Fra - notice how unreadable that comment is? That's why we don't put code into comments.

Comment: Yes Tom. Next time I edit the question adding the code so it is more clear what I mean. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you mean this. Some kind of iterative function closing in on a value?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

c = 1
d = 1

b = 1
while True:
    a = 3 * b + c
    new_b = (a - d) / 5
    if b - new_b <= 0.25:
        break
    b = new_b

print(a, new_b)
```

Comment: I think you meant `a - d`, not `a - 5`?

Comment: yes Tom! This is what i meant. Thank you very very much! I had never used the "while True"!

Answer (score 0):

Roughly this:

```
b, c, d = [1]*3

while True:
    a=3*b + c     
    b= (a - d)/5
    if condition:
        break
```

You just need to fill out `condition`